# Change Div Content with JavaScript, onmouseover and onmouseout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, dom

I have the following code:

```
window.onload = function createDivs() { 
    for(var i = 1;i<29;i++) {
        var div = document.createElement("div"); 
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        var n1 = document.createTextNode("Cell " + i);
        var n2 = document.createTextNode(i + " Cell");
        div.style.width = "100px";
        div.style.height  = "100px";
        div.style.border = "1px solid red";
        div.style.cssFloat = "left";
        div.style.margin = "1px"
        div.className = i;
        body.appendChild(div);
    }
    div.onmouseover = function() {
        this.appendChild(n1);
    },
    div.onmouseout = function() {
        this.appendChild(n2);
    } 
}
```

what I want to acheive

1. **on mouseover of each div, the div should have a text of cell 1, cell 2, ..... upto cel 28. But I am just getting Cell 28 on hover for each cell.**

**2.  I also want to achieve that onmouseout, the cell should have "`1 cell`" as text, but its not working.**

Any help is appreciated.

http://jsbin.com/iXuLEDE/7/edit?html,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is coming from your closure over `n1` and `n2`. The simplest solution to that is the following.

From this:

```
div.onmouseover = function() {
    this.appendChild(n1);
}
```

To this:

```
div.onmouseover = (function(text) {
      return function () {
          this.innerHTML = text;
      }
}(n1.textContent));
```

This way you are using a copy of the text node (by using it as a parameter to a function) rather than as a closure later on.

**UPDATE**

Just read the second part of your question, this should work:

```
div.onmouseover = (function(text) {
    return function() {
        this.innerHTML = text;
    };
}("Cell " + i));
div.onmouseout = (function(text) {
    return function() {
        this.innerHTML = text;
    };
}(i + " Cell"));
```

**USING TEXT NODES**

```
function createDivs() { 
    for(var i = 1;i<29;i++) {
        var div = document.createElement("div"); 
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        div.style.width = "100px";
        div.style.height  = "100px";
        div.style.border = "1px solid red";
        div.style.cssFloat = "left";
        div.style.margin = "1px"
        div.className = i;
        var n1 = document.createTextNode("Cell " + i);
        var n2 = document.createTextNode(i + " Cell");
        body.appendChild(div);
        div.onmouseover = (function(n_text1, n_text2) {
          return function() {
              if (n_text2.parentNode == this) {
                  this.removeChild(n_text2);
              }
              this.appendChild(n_text1);
          };
        }(n1, n2));
        div.onmouseout = (function(n_text1, n_text2) {
          return function() {
              if (n_text1.parentNode == this) {
                  this.removeChild(n_text1);
              }
              this.appendChild(n_text2);
          };
        }(n1, n2));
    }
}
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Mk5e5/

Comment: Thanks for pointing towards closures. I have been trying to learn closures. However using your solution, I ran into another problem. Though I can use mouseover functionality but when I do mouseout, It creates another problem
http://jsbin.com/iXuLEDE/7/edit

I know there is nothing wrong with closures, but how do I remove text node on mouseout.

Comment: @Mike see update and I've also posted a link to a working jsFiddle (not a huge fan of jsbin).

Comment: what is the difference between text nodes approach and the above one? which one do you prefer personally?

Comment: @Mike - it depends really, setting the innerHTML is the easier option as long as there isn't going to be any other stuff in the div. The text node means that you don't have to worry about whether or not there's other children in the div.

Comment: Thanks, Just accepted it. you have provided some good info about closures, that topic that never came my way.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the code like this

```
    window.onload = function createDivs() { 
    for(var i = 1;i<29;i++) {
        var div = document.createElement("div"); 
        div.setAttribute("index", i);
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        div.style.width = "100px";
        div.style.height  = "100px";
        div.style.border = "1px solid red";
        div.style.cssFloat = "left";
        div.style.margin = "1px"
        div.className = i;
        body.appendChild(div);
        div.onmouseover = function() {
          var n1 = document.createTextNode("Cell " + this.getAttribute("index"));
          this.appendChild(n1);

        } ,
        div.onmouseout = function() {
        var n2 = document.createTextNode(this.getAttribute("index") + " Cell");
          this.appendChild(n2);

        } 

    }
}
```

You should add event for each `div` in loop

Comment: That will have the exact same problem as the current code. `i` will always be 29.

Answer (score 0):

Try to understand javascript closures, specially inside for loops. Check this excellent explanation in this blog post: http://www.mennovanslooten.nl/blog/post/62

Change your createDivs function to:

```
function createDivs() { 

for(var i = 1;i<29;i++) {
    var div = document.createElement("div"); 
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    div.style.width = "100px";
    div.style.height  = "100px";
    div.style.border = "1px solid red";
    div.style.cssFloat = "left";
    div.style.margin = "1px"
    div.className = i;
    body.appendChild(div);
    div.onmouseover = (function(value) { 
        return function() {
            var n1 = document.createTextNode("Cell " + value);
            this.appendChild(n1);
        }
    })(i);
    div.onmouseout = (function(value) { 
        return function() {
            var n2 = document.createTextNode(value + " Cell");
            this.appendChild(n2);
        }
    })(i);

};
```

};

Comment: Thanks, but I also want to remove the n1 node on mouseout. Any thoughts?
http://jsbin.com/iXuLEDE/7/edit

Comment: I guess for this example, within the onmouseout function you could loop over the children and remove them, so for example:        div.onmouseout = (function(value) { 
   return function() {
    var children = this.childNodes;
    for(var i=0;i<children.length;i++) {
     this.removeChild(children[i]);
    }
   }
        })(i);

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because when your `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` functions are executed, the value of your text variables is "cell 28."  Also, your child removal was a little off, if I interpret your intentions correctly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function createDivs(n) { 
      for(var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        var div = document.createElement("div"); 
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

        div.style.width = "100px";
        div.style.height  = "100px";
        div.style.border = "1px solid red";
        div.style.cssFloat = "left";
        div.style.margin = "1px"
        div.className = i;
        body.appendChild(div);

        div.onmouseover = function() {
          if (this.childNodes.length > 0) this.removeChild(this.childNodes[0]);
          var n_text = document.createTextNode("Cell " + this.className);
          this.appendChild(n_text);
        },
        div.onmouseout = function() {
          if (this.childNodes.length > 0) this.removeChild(this.childNodes[0]);
          var n_text = document.createTextNode(this.className + " Cell");
          this.appendChild(n_text);
        }  
      }   
    }

    createDivs(28)

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I also changed your if statement so you pass the number of cells you want instead of the number of cells +1.

Comment: It would also make it easier if you used `innerHTML` instead of using children for text, but I kept the children in there because I thought maybe you would use more than text later on.